# Counting binary sequences satisfying a certain condition

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

We are given a binary sequence $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ and an integer $l\leq n$. Let $A$ denote the set of integer sequences $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_l)$ satisfying $1\leq\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\ldots<\alpha_l\leq n$. For $\alpha\in A$ and $y\in\{0,1\}^n$, let $f_\alpha(y)$ be the length $l$ subsequence of $y$ with indices $\alpha_i$; that is,
$$
  f_\alpha(y)=(y_{\alpha_1},\ldots,y_{\alpha_l}).
$$
What is the size of the following set?
$$
  \{f_\alpha(y)\mid y\in\{0,1\}^n,\,\alpha\in A,\,
    \neg f_\alpha(x)\vee f_\alpha(y)=(1,\ldots,1)\}
$$
For example, suppose $n=7$, $l=5$ and $x=1101111$. The set contains four elements, namely
$$
  01111,\,10111,\,11011,\,11111.
$$
We can express each element as $f_\alpha(y)$ for some $\alpha,y$ satisfying the condition as follows. Note that we can do so in more than one way, but we only want to count each length 5 sequence once.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  01111&=&f_{3,4,5,6,7}(0001111),\\
  10111&=&f_{1,3,5,6,7}(1000111),\\
  11011&=&f_{1,2,3,6,7}(1100011),\\
  11111&=&f_{3,4,5,6,7}(0011111).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

**Incorrect solution:** Let $||x||_1$ denote the hamming weight of $x$. Given that $||x||_1 = k$, there exist $2^{n-k}$ binary sequences $y \in \{0,1\}^n$, that have a $1$ at at least all the indices where $x$ is $1$. Hence, such $y$ satisfies the desired condition for each $\alpha\in A$. Hence, the number of $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations from such sequences (that is, sequences of the form $f_\alpha(y)$) that are part of the solution is given by the expression: $2^{n-k} \dbinom{n}{l}$. Similarly, if we consider the $y's$ that match the $1$ bits of $x$ at exactly $k-1$ spots, then the number of such $y's$ is also $2^{n-k}$ as we are still fixing the value of exactly $k$ bits. In this manner, we get the total count for the $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations from $\{0,1\}^n$ that match $x$ as:
\begin{equation}
2^{n-k} \cdot \sum\limits_{w=0}^k \dbinom{n-w}{l}. 
\end{equation} 
But, the above expression clearly overcounts as the $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations from different $y's$ overlap. Now, we can go with an inclusion-exclusion principle based solution but I wasn't able to find a closed-form expression by moving in that direction. Note that all that we are given is the hamming weight of $x$, and we have no knowledge of the exact number of transitions (i.e., $0$ to $1$ or vice-versa) in $x$. It is easy to see that the hamming weight of a binary sequence can be used to upper and lower bound the number of transitions in it. But, I am not sure if doing that is of any help here.

An algorithm to solve the problem might maintain a counter $c$ initialized to $0$ to store the count. It should first list all $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations one by one for each $y \in \{0,1\}^n$. Hence, we consider the $|A|=\dbinom{n}{l}$ ways to select unique sets of $l$ indices $\alpha$. Next, for each $\alpha$, we select the corresponding sub-sequences of $x$ and $y$, which are denoted as $f_\alpha(x)$ and $f_\alpha(y)$, respectively. Finally, we see whether $\neg f_\alpha(x) \vee f_\alpha(y)$ gives an $l$ bits long sequence of $1's$. If yes, then the counter $c$ is incremented by $1$. But, we must avoid the overcounting scenario as described in the example above.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @hardmath I couldn't find a succinct title, so went with the existing one. And yes, $\neg x$ is given!

Comment: @hardmath The body of the question considers counting the distinct $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations that satisfy the condition, hence introducing the additional burden to deal with filtering out identical $l$ bits long strings that arise from different strings $y \in 2^n$.

Comment: Okay, I tried to parse out the extra condition but didn't see what you were getting at. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It's not sufficiently clear to me what you mean by "distinct $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations" -- could you please spell out in more detail what sorts of objects these are (strings? strings marked with the indices they came from?) and when you consider them distinct? One thing that threw me off was that you require $\neg f_l(x) \vee f_l(y)$ to be $n$ bits long even though $f_l(x)$ was introduced as $l$ bits long. Is that a typo? Also, where you say "the bits at $l$-out-of-$n$ indices of $x$", do you mean at $l$ particular indices out of the $n$? If so, how are these particular indices determined?

Comment: @joriki You're correct, $\neg f_l(x) \vee f_l(y)$ should output $l$ bits. I've corrected that typo, thanks! The strings under consideration are binary strings of length $n~(n$ bits long). Index $i$ represents the bits $x[i]$, in the binary string $x \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$.  Yes, by "the bits at l-out-of-n indices of x" I mean the the bits of $x$, at the selected $l$ indices. The $l$ indices are just (all) $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations, but note that we want all such $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations of all $y \in \mathbb{Z}_2^n$ that satisfy the condition $\neg f_l(x) \vee f_l(y) =1 \dots 1$.

Comment: Thanks, the edit has made some things clearer. What's still confusing me is how you use $l$. It seems to be simultaneously an integer length of strings and some sort of label for combinations. Shouldn't it be $f_k$ rather than $f_l$? Since the $k_i$ are what determines this $f$, whereas all of them share the same length $l$?

Comment: @joriki $f$ selects the $l$ bits corresponding to the chosen $l$ indices, and hence I used $l$ in the subscript. On the other hand, $k \leq l$ is the hamming weight of the $l$ bits long string outputted by $f_l$. So, I'm not sure which one of $k$ and $l$ makes more sense.

Comment: @NoviceGeek I think joriki's comment was using $k$ to refer to the sequence of indices $k_1,\ldots,k_l$, not $k=\|x\|_1$. I also would find it helpful to clarify this; is there a single fixed subset of $l$ indices, or are you considering all possible subsets (ie $l$-out-of-$n$ combinations)? If the latter, must $y$ satisfy the equation for at least one subset or for all subsets?

Comment: @stewbasic: Indeed, that's what I was referring to. That $k$ is reused for something else later is yet another instance of notational overload; these two have nothing to do with each other as far as I can tell.

Comment: @stewbasic We're considering all possible subsets $(l$-out-of-$n$ combinations). And yes, $y$ must satisfy at least one such subset. I see joriki's point! $k$ denotes the hamming weight in the question body. When I say "we fix $k$ indices", it means that the value of $k$ bits is fixed, where $k = ||x||_1$.

Comment: @stewbasic I've edited the question. Please see if it makes more sense now!

Comment: @joriki I've edited the question. Please see if it makes more sense now!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. You're still talking about "each $f_l$" even though, if I understand correctly, $l$ has one fixed value throughout the entire text. "Each" must be followed by something of which there is more than one. If I understand your intention correctly, what you denote by $f_l$ should be denoted by $f_i$, since it's the tuple $i$ that actually distinguishes the various functions.

Comment: @joriki It seems like someone suggested an edit and it was automatically performed by the website. Strange! I will re-edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: It still feels like you could e.g. permute the indices in $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily since you're not using the order of the sequence at all.  Can you give an example as to why this _isn't_ just dependent on the Hamming weight of $x$, if you think it isn't? (Also, where did the problem originate? Is there any additional structure?)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I've edited the problem, and added an example as to why the hamming weight method overcounts. I'm a beginner who is exploring combinatorics. I just thought of this problem after looking at similar but simpler problems .

Comment: @joriki I've edited the problem statement and added an example to clarify things further. Please see if it's clearer. Thanks again! I really appreciate your time!

Comment: @NoviceGeek the question is still not quite clear to me, but your example helps. Could you give the desired count in your example (and ideally the list of sequences you counted)?

Comment: @stewbasic I've added how an ideal procedure (according to me) should proceed to attack the problem. Hopefully, the procedure outlines all the requirements that the solution must satisfy. Thanks!

Comment: @NoviceGeek I think this is what you are asking, could you confirm? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4667/197161

Comment: @stewbasic Exactly! Strangely, the question succinctly presents the same problem. An unlikely coincidence indeed!!

Comment: @NoviceGeek It's not a coincidence, I wrote it as a proposed edit to your question. I've merged it into your question; please check if I have changed your intended meaning.

Comment: @stewbasic Oh, I see! Indeed, your question precisely communicates the intended meaning. Thanks!